# MySQL query not returning as expected

Tags: php, mysql

```
$user_id = $id['id'];
$shop_name = $_POST['shop_name'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN shopaholic f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = '". $user_id ."' AND f.shop_name = '" . $shop_name . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        var_dump($row['feed_id'])
    }
```

This returns null despite the fact that the variables are populated as expected.

I think the problem is with the use of `'` and `"` as my text editor isn't showing what follows in the colours I expect it to.

Comment: have you tried echo'ing or error_loggin the $query variable to see what the query looks like?

Comment: It comes back as `SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN shopaholic f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = '1' AND f.shop_name = 'Shop'` - both variables are as expected.

Comment: When you use double quotes, you can include variables directly into the string without concatenation (as in `$query = "Select * FROM table where id = $user_id AND city = '$city';"`) While not an answer, this may help you simplify your quote usage.

Comment: Inner join is probably the culprit. Try left JOIN to see if anything is output. Inner join requires both sides of the query to match at least one record.

Comment: If you run that query in MySQL workbench (or something along those lines), does it return records?

Comment: @MitchGoshorn thanks for clarifying - that's been a point of confusion for me.

Comment: @ProfileTwist I'm afraid that doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you believe its an error, you can check in PHP using the `mysqli_errno` and `mysqli_error` functions. The query _looks_ okay to me, so it may be that you're simply having no rows returned.

Comment: One potential problem: Is your `user_id` an integer or a string?  According to your query, you've surrounded it with single quotes, which to mysql will indicate that it is a string, which may prevent it from matching your records if this column is stored as an integer.

Comment: It's an integer in the database. I've removed the quotes (and the query echoes with the variable properly in place) but unfortunately still no desired results :(

Comment: Did you try to var_dump() whole $row? What is in output?

Comment: I can't see the output because the PHP is part of an AJAX request - any suggestions?

Comment: So how do you know that var_dump($row['feed_id']) returns NULL? Try to write result to file. One more question: Do you have semicolon after that var_dump($row['feed_id'])?

Comment: Same - doesn't return anything.

Comment: You can run the PHP page being posted to with predefined (rather than POST) variables for testing.  Alternatively, you can (usually) access your browser's development interface and find the returned data in the network tabs.

Comment: May be it is syntax error because of missing semicolon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in double and single quotes. Moreover, as `$user_id` is `INTEGER` is not necessary AND `;` after `var_dump($row['feed_id'])`. Try again:

```
$user_id = $id['id'];
$shop_name = $_POST['shop_name'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN shopaholic f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = $user_id AND f.shop_name = '$shop_name'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        var_dump($row['feed_id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, to my mind this is fractionally more readable...

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM sh_subscriptions s 
  JOIN shopaholic f 
    ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id 
 WHERE s.user_id = $user_id
   AND f.shop_name = '$shop_name';
";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = $id['id'];
$shop_name = $_POST['shop_name'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN shopaholic f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = '". $user_id ."' AND f.shop_name = '" . $shop_name . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        var_dump($row['feed_id'])
    }
```

Here is a run down of what you should do/consider for the future:

1. Remove the single quotes enclosing $user_id. It is an integer and it is uncessary.
2. You should not use procedural mode to query the mysql as you have to carry the $con connection at all times.
3. How are you connecting to the database? If this is an ajax page you need to do that on that page as well.
4. You should be careful with injecting $shop_name directly into the query. Validation is a must. At the bare minimum, the string should be escaped.
5. The query string should be first built in a separate variable i.e. `$sql` and then run in `mysqli_query($sql)`. It is much easier to debug and makes the code more readable.
6. You shouldn't be selecting all the columns by the star `*` operator. Define exactly which columns you are pulling. Better performance and make code more manageable.

To assist in debugging:

Install firebug on firefox and run your tests on FF. You can use chrome as well but I prefer FF.

1. First check that your ajax request is not getting a 404 error and that your code is actually sending the data over to the server.
2. On the ajax page, echo the query string `$sql`. Then use firebug to get the response. Clearly, this will cause a javascript error as this does not return a JSON or some other time of regular data.
3. Run the query string directly in phpmyadmin. If it doesn't work there then clearly there is an error with the formulation of the query string.
4. If the query runs in phpmyadmin as expected, keep going with the debugging...

I know that's a lot of text but here is how your code would look if I coded it. Realize there is a lot of stuff going in the background, but at least you get the idea on how to setup a 100% proof system:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$shop_name = $form->validate('POST', 'shop_name', some_validation);

if ($form->is_valid()) {

  $sql = "SELECT s.column1, s.column2
          FROM sh_subscriptions s
          INNER JOIN shopaholic f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id
          WHERE s.user_id = $user_id AND f.shop_name = '{$extender->sanitizeSQL($shop_name['valid']}'";

  // Run query and insert the results into '$result_name' variable
  $mysqli->query($sql, 'result_name');

  // If at least one row
  if ($result_name->num_rows > 0) {

    // Process code
  }
  else {

     // No records
  }

}
else {

  // Invalid user input
}
```